# Ubuntu imageMagick does not convert PDF to PNG from www-data (php)

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, imagemagick

I have a problem when I want to convert a pdf file using a simple php script like:

```
<?php
    shell_exec("convert pdf.pdf image.png");
?>
```

The conversion works fine when converting from terminal (SSH connection), but only if I'm logged in as myself. The following will give no error nor an output file 'image.png'.

```
sudo su www-data
<enters password>
convert pdf.pdf image.png
```

Comment: Is it working when you run the command direct on your console?

Comment: If you have solved it, you can write and accept an answer for yourself.

Comment: If you have found a solution to your problem, post it as an answer and mark the answer as accepted. Do *not* put "solved" or "fixed" in your title to indicate that your question has been answered, use the facilities the system provides.

Comment: i dont think hes gona do this, il make it for him...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file/folder permissions are wrong, imagemagick (convert) needs write permissions:

```
sudo chmod g+w folder
```

check out http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html for a good help/explanation what the file/folder "modes" are and how they work.