# SVG to PNG with imagick

Tags: php, svg, imagick

I have a svg which has some images embedded into it. Something like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<svg 
  width="483" height="710" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g>
    <title>Layer 1</title>
    <image 
      id="svg_1"
      y="0" x="0"
      height="199" width="176"
      xlink:href="http://192.168.3.2/images/1341920552_test.png"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

So when I do a convert via command line as my regular linux user it converts it to PNG just fine. But if I do the same with the user www-data then it does convert but the images dont showup in the resulting PNG other things like lines etc do showup.

The very same problem exists if I convert with the PHP imagick library. The attached images dont showup. Any sort of help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the right of the folder used for the conversion output. There is a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11267305/795876

Comment: Nope the output is actually getting written. The problem is that the output only has the drawing like eclipse, lines etc. The embedded images like jpegs, pngs in the SVG dont show up on the converted output.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of experimentation's noticed that all users have this problem if they are logged in via ssh. The normal desktop user who is logged into the GUI session can convert without any issues.

I solved the issue by removing the http URL referring the embedded image and adding the local file system path. This slows down my app with the current design. But anyway this is solved for the time being.

I would like to know the reason though as to why this is like this.

Comment: I saw a comment from someone on another post regarding this. Long story short, users' accessing your site don't have the same permissions as you would on a shell, which should be the case for security purposes. Of which, the convert command in `/usr/bin/` doesn't have full permissions, ie 777. So a user accessing your site comes in, a shell is opened as a site user, and they can't use the convert command. There are several solutions... chmod of the convert command to 777 or you could open a new shell, change user, run convert, and close it. Probably not recommended though.